# designing a method in java so that it would return the date into DD/MM/YYYY FORMAT

Tags: java

I am receiving a `Date` as `String` now the `Date` will be in form of `String` in (dd/mm/yyyy or dd/mm/yy or dd-mm-yy or dd-mm-yyyy) but it can be in the below formats as shown below

```
16-Feb-2014
16/02/2014
16/02/14
```

as shown above it is clear that date format would be the UK format so now I have to finally convert all the above dates into DD/MM/YYYY format , so I have designed a method that will be receiving a string date  and will finally convert the above dates  in DD/MM/YYYY so P have done this below code please advise **how can I modify it further so that return type of this method would be of date type and it simply would return the format of DD/MM/YYYY** , so now please advise is it correct implementation

```
public  Date convertStringToDate(String stringValue) {
        Date iceDate = null;
        java.util.Date javaDate = new java.util.Date();
                String[] formatStrings = { "dd/MM/yyyy", "dd-MMM-yyyy" ,"dd/MM/YY" , "dd-MM-YY"};

        for (String formatString : formatStrings) {

            try {
                javaDate = new SimpleDateFormat(formatString)
                        .parse(stringValue);
                iceDate = new Date(javaDate);
                return iceDate;
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                logger.warn("##$$$$$### Error in invoice inside convertStringToDate method : ##$$$$$$#### "
                        + ErrorUtility.getStackTraceForException(e));

            }
        }
        return null;

    }
```

now in this method I want to add one more functionality that is year is coming as two digit 'YY' then I have to preif '20' in front of it lets say if year is coming as 16 then finally it should be of 2016 please advise how to achieve this

Comment: A `Date` object doesn't have a format. You can create any `DateFormat` for it that you wish and use it.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Request you to please show it  it would be a gret if you please can modify my above code so that i can grasp more Thanks in advance

Comment: @nareshsaxena You could've already googled and found plenty of examples on how to use a `DateFormat`. Show some initiative, it's the mark of a good programmer.

Comment: @Kayaman Thanks for the advise but please check i have already coded a lot , my query is how to achieve ,

Comment: Just like `SimpleDateFormat.parse()` can be used to convert a `String` to a `Date`, the `format()` method can be used to convert a `Date` to a `String`. As RealSkeptic said, a `Date` doesn't have a format, so you need to return a `String`, not a `Date` if you want to force a specific format to the result.

Answer (score 1):

A Date doesn't have any format.  You can format the date any way you wish.

Here are the results of a test program I wrote.

```
16-Feb-2014 -> 16/02/2014
16/02/2014 -> 16/02/2014
16/02/14 -> 16/02/2014
```

And here's the test program.  Hopefully, you can use this example to create your own Java tests in the future.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class DateFormattingTest {

    private static final SimpleDateFormat outputDate = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "dd/MM/yyyy");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateFormattingTest test = new DateFormattingTest();
        convertDate(test, "16-Feb-2014");
        convertDate(test, "16/02/2014");
        convertDate(test, "16/02/14");
    }

    private static void convertDate(DateFormattingTest test, String dateString) {
        java.util.Date date = test.convertStringToDate(dateString);
        System.out.println(dateString + " -> " + outputDate.format(date));
    }

    public java.util.Date convertStringToDate(String stringValue) {
        String[] formatStrings = { "dd/MM/yy", "dd-MM-yy", "dd-MMM-yyyy" };

        for (String formatString : formatStrings) {
            try {
                java.util.Date date = new SimpleDateFormat(formatString)
                        .parse(stringValue);
                return date;
            } catch (ParseException e) {

            }
        }

        return null;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Strings Are Not Date-Times

Do not confuse a date-time value (or object) with a String generated to represent that value in a culturally-appropriate human-readable format.

If receiving such a String representation, parse it into a date-time object. Perform your business logic. Then as expected by the user, generate another String representation to present as output.

In other words, dates and date-times do not have a format. From a date or date-time you can generate a String representation in any particular format.

### ISO 8601

Whenever possible I suggest you use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) string formats for various date-time values. These formats are designed to be unambiguous and easily parseable.

For date-only values, the standard format is `YYYY-MM-DD`.

## java.time

The java.util.Date class used in the Question is inappropriate for a date-only value lacking time-of-day and time zone.

Also, the java.util.Date/.Calendar & java.text.SimpleDateFormat classes are outmoded as of Java 8. The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework built into Java 8 and later supplants the troublesome old java.util.Date/.Calendar classes. The new classes are inspired by the highly successful [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) framework, intended as its successor, similar in concept but re-architected. Defined by [JSR 310](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310). Extended by the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project. See the [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

### `LocalDate`

These classes offer a [`LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class for date-only values.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "Europe/London" );
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now ( zoneId );
```

### Formatters

We can parse an input String using a [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/package-summary.html) in the [java.time.format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/package-summary.html) package.

Set up a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) of expected formatters. In real work, I would do this once and keep the list around for repeated use.

Note how we specify a [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) by which to translate the text of the month name. If omitted, the JVM’s current default Locale is silently applied. Better to specify than implicitly rely on default. The other formatters lack any such text (month or day names), so no need for a Locale.

As for two-digit years, the century of 2000s is assumed. Per the doc:

> If the count of letters is two … will parse using the base value of 2000, resulting in a year within the range 2000 to 2099 inclusive.

By the way, always using four-digit year rather than two will make your life easier.

```
List<DateTimeFormatter> formatters = new ArrayList<> ();
// Month name.
formatters.add ( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "dd-MMM-yyyy" , Locale.UK ) ); // Note the use of a Locale by which to translate the month name.
// Four-digit year. Zero-padded numbers.
formatters.add ( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "dd/MM/yyyy" ) );
formatters.add ( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "dd-MM-yyyy" ) );
// Two-digit year. Zero-padded numbers.
formatters.add ( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "dd/MM/yy" ) );
formatters.add ( DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern ( "dd-MM-yy" ) );
```

Call on each of those formatters until one of them works. When one fails by throwing the expected exception, ignore the exception and move on to the next formatter. If a formatter works, remember the resulting LocalDate object. If none work, we have a problem – bad input probably.

```
String input = "16-Feb-2014";  // or "16/02/2014" , "16-02-2014" , "16/02/14" , "16-02-14".
// String input = "16-févr.-2014";  // French input should fail.
String output = null;
LocalDate localDate = null;
for ( DateTimeFormatter formatter : formatters ) {
    try {
        localDate = LocalDate.parse ( input , formatter );
        break; // Bail out of FOR loop on first hit.
    } catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {
        // Ignore this exception, as we expect some mismatches.
    }
}
```

### Generate String

If we successfully instantiated a LocalDate object, generate a String representation of its value to report to the user. By the way, if returning to business logic rather than a human user, pass the `LocalDate` object itself rather than a String.

```
if ( localDate != null ) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = formatters.get ( 1 ); // Grab the second formatter.
    output = localDate.format ( formatter );
} else {  // Else localDate is null, so none of our expected patterns matched.
    System.out.println ( "ERROR - Unexpected input. String representation of date value not matching any of " + formatters.size () + " expected formats. Message # c27373a5-7faa-4d60-8f3c-ae785ed52e3a." );
}
```

Dump to console. The java.time classes use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats by default when generating (or parsing) String representations of date-time values.

```
System.out.println ( "input: " + input + " → localDate: " + localDate + " → output: " + output );
```

> input: 16-Feb-2014 → localDate: 2014-02-16 → output: 16/02/2014

Answer (score -1):

you could check the input pattern by regular expression.

For your reference:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

```
Pattern.compile("a*b"); 
Matcher m = p.matcher("aaaaab"); 
boolean b = m.matches();
```

Comment: Thanks for the advise i am using java 5 but yeah regular expression will work in java 5 also can you please show a example

Comment: For detail, you should find some time to study it. regular expression is very useful in many aspect

Comment: Regular expressions can be tricky, and are pretty much the worst choice if you're dealing with something like date formats.

Comment: My design is that using regular expression to verify if it match the date format. When casting string to date time, simpledateformat should be used.